# Why does Ruby throw NameError here?

Tags: ruby

When I run the code below:

```
puts s while (s = gets.chomp) != '42'
```

Ruby will throw `` Undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object (NameError) ``. Why?

Comment: By the way, the same work can be done by `print while gets != "42\n"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is parsed left-to-right, `s` is used before it is defined.

Initialization order of local variables was changed somewhere around Ruby 1.9, I believe. You should restructure your code or upgrade to a more recent version of Ruby. (Note that 1.8 is no longer maintained.)

Answer (score 2):

`s` isn't defined yet, at the `puts s` statement.

What you're doing is basically equivalent to:

```
begin
  puts s                           # s is undefined here
end while (s = gets.chomp) != '42'
```

Put the while block first to make it work:

```
while (s = gets.chomp) != '42'     # s gets defined here
  puts s
end
```

Comment: Works in IRB Ruby version 1.9.3. So it isn't the equivalent of the `begin/end` statement.

Comment: @Humza: actually, I just edited the response. It does NOT work in irb. It worked in my first try because I had an f which was previously defined.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried in Ruby 1.9.3 as well as 2.1 and it's working in both of them.

Comment: @Humza: That's because you're carting around an f which exists already. The statement is equivalent to the begin/end statement, btw.

Comment: I stand corrected! Thanks! Please edit your answer so I can re-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make a single line you can get s defined first, but it's ugly

```
while (s = gets.chomp) != '42' ; puts s ; end
```